# How to decleare multiple state variables using loop - react state hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to declare some state variable like : processId_1, processId_2, processId_3 ..... processId_n .

`const [processId, setProcessId] = useState(0)`;
I just want to use loop on the code to declare these variable.
Something like that:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    const [processId["".concat("_",index)], setProcessId]["".concat("_",index)] = useState(0);
    
}
```

[image]

I also want to send them as props. How to do that.

Comment: Don't try and create multiple state values, instead, have one state value `processes`, that is an _array_ of values.

Comment: why not store the id as an array? or a set? `const [processIds, setProcessIds] = setState(new Set())`

Comment: Take a look at this post on ["Variable" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create an array of these states. So code would look like this:

```
const [processIds, setProcessIds] = useState([
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'processId 1'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'processId 2'
    }
]);

const handleClick = () => {
  setProcessIds([...processIds].map(pr => {
        if(pr.id === '1') {
          return {
            ...pr,
            name: 'processId is edited'
          }
        }
        else return pr;
      }))
}

<button onClick={handleClick}>
</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

It is possible to add keys into object dynamically like this:

```
const  obj = {};

for (let i = 10; i <= 20; i++) {
    obj['processId_' + i] = 0;
}
```

An example:

```js
const  obj = {};

for (let i = 10; i <= 20; i++) {
    obj['processId_' + i] = 0;
}    

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After your comment I write my code as below:

const initialProcessIds = {
    processId_11: 0,
processId_12: 0,
processId_13: 0,
processId_14: 0,
processId_15: 0,
processId_16: 0,
processId_17: 0,
processId_18: 0,
processId_19: 0,}

const [processIds, setProcessIds] = useState(initialProcessIds);

But can you help me achieve this:



const initialProcessIds = {

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    processId_1["".concat("",index)]: 0,
    
}}

Comment: @Md.TazimulIslamRaj please, see my updated answer